# Grouping data in list of lists of floats in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm receiving the following orderbook data from an API:

```
myData = [[9656.37, 0.063], [9656.32, 0.688], [9656.21, 0.729], [9656.07, 0.618], [9656.01, 0.598], [9656.0, 0.917], [9655.92, 0.417], [9655.84, 0.403], [9655.81, 1.032], [9655.6, 1.394], [9655.5, 0.043], [9655.41, 0.6], [9655.32, 0.441], [9655.31, 3.359], [9655.29, 0.15], [9655.0, 11.463], [9654.89, 0.612], [9654.88, 0.613], [9654.87, 0.602], [9654.74, 0.382], [9654.69, 0.75], [9654.63, 8.106], [9654.62, 0.8], [9654.58, 0.12], [9654.44, 0.54], [9654.38, 0.311], [9654.33, 2.758], [9654.31, 0.72], [9654.25, 0.02], [9654.14, 4.0], [9654.0, 0.155], [9653.95, 0.642], [9653.91, 0.5], [9653.83, 0.063], [9653.81, 0.6], [9653.38, 0.05], [9653.34, 0.1], [9653.31, 0.207], [9653.3, 0.001], [9653.28, 0.008], [9653.25, 3.351], [9653.03, 10.0], [9653.02, 0.651], [9652.98, 0.105], [9652.92, 0.002], [9652.9, 3.589], [9652.82, 2.07], [9652.8, 1.25], [9652.7, 0.4], [9652.66, 5.5], [9652.5, 0.006], [9652.48, 0.01], [9652.4, 0.207], [9652.39, 2.799], [9652.21, 0.174], [9652.14, 0.063], [9652.12, 8.106], [9652.09, 1.591], [9652.07, 4.0], [9652.06, 0.16], [9652.0, 0.006], [9651.9, 0.858], [9651.5, 0.006], [9651.49, 0.207], [9651.45, 0.106], [9651.37, 0.001], [9651.28, 0.7], [9651.21, 0.001], [9651.2, 1.377], [9651.16, 0.613], [9651.07, 0.16], [9651.06, 0.64], [9651.01, 0.75], [9651.0, 1.001], [9650.99, 2.637], [9650.94, 0.063], [9650.93, 2.82], [9650.87, 0.098], [9650.77, 4.782], [9650.6, 0.001], [9650.59, 12.279], [9650.56, 0.008], [9650.4, 0.008], [9650.23, 0.622], [9650.21, 0.008], [9650.2, 0.008], [9650.1, 8.106], [9650.09, 0.5], [9650.05, 1.036], [9650.0, 7.573], [9649.89, 0.5], [9649.76, 2.461], [9649.68, 0.207], [9649.6, 0.016], [9649.48, 0.059], [9649.4, 0.008], [9649.3, 10.0], [9649.29, 0.651], [9649.25, 1.286], [9649.21, 0.008] .... ]
```

This is just a snippet of the data, the total list is big, around 999 elements. Since this list is too unnecessarily big, i'm thinking of some ways to reduce it, here is what i came up with:

Grouping the data: instead of having `9656.37`, `9656.32`, `9656.21` i can have only `9656`. This would receive the amount of data a lot. The problem with this, is that i would also need to sum the second elements of every element, so in this case (see the data above), `9656 = 0.063 + 0.688 + 0.729 + 0.598 + 0.917`. Then, the same should be done with 9655 and so on.

I don't have high knowledge of Python yet, and every time i try to solve this i end up having a lot of `for` loops that make the code a mess, without getting closer to my expected output: `[[9656, 3.613], [9655, 19.302]...]`

Is there any example about doing this particular task, some built-in function or practice that would help me achieving this? Any kind of advice is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Please, can you share the desired output ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with for loops, especially if it works and you are still learning. After leraning some more you will probably learn how to replace them with list comprehensions or with functions from builtin modules. Can you share the code you have?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa nothing is wrong with those, of course, the problem is that i would probably end up making too many of them, making my code spaghetti. Yes, i'm learning list comprehensions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this, grouping on the `int` value of the first element of each sublist, and then summing the second elements of each sublist over the group:

```
import itertools
newData = [[k, sum(v[1] for v in g)] for k, g in itertools.groupby(myData, lambda v: int(v[0]))]
```

Output:

```
[
 [9656, 3.6129999999999995],
 [9655, 19.302],
 [9654, 20.488999999999997],
 [9653, 16.173000000000002],
 [9652, 30.038],
 [9651, 6.42],
 [9650, 40.549],
 [9649, 15.195999999999998]
]
```

Note this works because your input data is sorted by the first element of each sublist. If that was not the case, you would need to sort it first e.g.

```
myData = sorted(myData, key=lambda v:int(v[0]))
```

Comment: With one small mention: it works because the inner lists are ordered based on the 1st element.

Comment: This is incredible! Works flawlessly! Just as a reference, before using your solution the number of elements was around 1000, now it's around 155-165. Thank you a lot!

Comment: About your last note: i'm using the exact same line to order the list, that's why it's ordered. So it's not a problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary

rounded float : sum of second terms

```
    result ={i:sum([j[1] for j in  [[round(i[0]),i[1]] for i in myData] if j[0]==i]) for i in {round(i[0]) for i in myData}}
```

Output:

```
    {9649: 12.011999999999999,
    9650: 21.044999999999998,
    9651: 28.244,
    9652: 17.986,
    9653: 27.284,
    9654: 10.309,
    9655: 27.997999999999998,
    9656: 6.902}
```